# Prove $\sin(x)< x$ when $x>0$ using LMVT

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, inequality, derivatives

According to Lagrange's Mean Value Theorem (LMVT), if a function $f(x)$ is continuous on $\left[a,b\right]$ and differentiable on $\left(a,b\right)$, then there exists some constant $c$ such that 
$$f'(c) = \frac{f(b) - f(a)}{b-a} $$

Now, I have the following question:

> Q) Using Lagrange's Mean value theorem, prove that $\sin(x) < x$ for $x > 0$.

This fact seems obvious from the graph of $\sin(x)$ and it's unit circle interpretation but I have no clue how I'd use LMVT to prove it. Any hints on how to start?

Comment: Other proofs of the same inequality can be found, for example, in these threads: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/407517/the-sine-inequality-frac2-pi-x-le-sin-x-le-x-for-0x-frac-pi2, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/125298/how-to-strictly-prove-sin-xx-for-0x-frac-pi2, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75130/how-to-prove-that-lim-limits-x-to0-frac-sin-xx-1

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let $x\in(0,2\pi].$ The derivative of $\sin(x)$ is $\cos(x)$, and so for some $c\in(0,x)$ we have $$\cos(c)=\frac{\sin(x)-\sin(0)}{x-0}=\frac{\sin(x)}{x}.$$ Since $\cos(c)<1$, the claim is proven for all $0<x\leq2\pi$. Then you can repeat the same argument, replacing $0$ by $2\pi$, and deduce the claim for all positive numbers.

Comment: Alternatively, $\sin(x)\leq 1< x$ whenever $x>2\pi$.

Comment: Or you can juste choose $x$ in $(0,+\infty)$ from the beginning.