# Does $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac {\sin{\frac 1 n}} {\sqrt n}$ converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

So my teacher gave a pretty tough (for me) problem in class today: Does the series $$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac {\sin{\frac 1 n}} {\sqrt n}
$$
converge or diverge?

So far I've thought of trying the Comparison Test and Ratio Test but couldn't really get anywhere. Intuitively I think it should converge, but how do I actually show this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since $\sin(1/n)\sim_{+\infty}1/n$ then the series converges iff $\frac{1/n}{\sqrt n}=\frac{1}{n^{3/2}}$ is the general term of a convergent series. Being $3/2>1$, that's the case, so your series converges.

Comment: Thanks, this was a nice solution. But how did you know $sin(1/n)$ approaches $1/n$? Is it part of a more general rule, or is it more of a fact one should know in and of itself?

Comment: It's simply the fundamental limit $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=1$.

Comment: Can you explain how one gets there from that? (I don't doubt it's right, I just still don't understand)

Comment: It's the asymptotical criterion for series convergence. Suppose you have to check the convergence of $\sum_{n\ge0}a_n$, but you can't handle the sequence $(a_n)_n$ successfully (e.g. ratio and root criteria fail). If you find another sequence $(b_n)_n$ such that $\lim_na_n/b_n=\lambda\in\Bbb R,\;\;\lambda\neq0$ then the two series $\sum_{n\ge0}a_n$ and $\sum_{n\ge0}b_n$ will have the same convergence character.

Comment: Ah sorry, I understood that part- I was asking about how one knows that $\sin{(1/n)}$ approaches $1/n$ by knowing the fundamental limit $\lim_{x \to 0}{\frac {\sin x} x}=1$

Comment: Change variable in the limit $x=1/n$.

Answer (score 2):

It suffices to use the fact that $|\sin x|\le|x|$. (See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75130/how-to-prove-that-lim-limits-x-to0-frac-sin-xx-1) or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/390899/sinx-inequality) or or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1035605/prove-x-geq-sin-x-on-0-pi-4). You can probably find this inequality in many other places.)

Then you get $|a_n| \le \frac1{n\sqrt n}$ for your series, which means that it is absolutely convergent.