# Derive the inequality $x<\arcsin \left(x\right)<\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, inequality

I found that I could do this with the Mean Value theorem and also found a similar question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/651391/showing-sinx-x-for-all-x0-using-the-mean-value-theorem) in the stackexchange and [Socratic](https://socratic.org/questions/using-mean-value-theorem-show-that-x-sin-1x-for-x-0) but couldn't solve the right hand side of the inequality.

I figured that by specifically choosing the function and the interval (combinations of the given question) we could prove that. But  I am lost tin selecting the appropriate function.

Can you guys please suggest some ideas and also some example sums where I could check these kind of sums.

***Thanks***

Comment: You can't prove it, because it is not true. Take $x=1$.

Comment: @Hanul Jeon Oops sorry I wrote the question wrong

Comment: Substitute $ x = \sin u$

Comment: Is this only for x>0? Because the inequality breaks down if x<0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty standard property of $\arcsin$ which is equivalent to the more famous inequality $\sin x <x<\tan x$ for $x\in(0, \pi/2)$.

A direct proof can be given by noting that if $x\in(0,1)$ and $t\in(0,x)$ then $$1<\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}<\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$ integrating the above with respect to $t$ on interval $[0,x]$ we get $$x<\arcsin x<\frac{x} {\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$ for all $x\in(0,1)$.

You can avoid integrals and achieve the same result via mean value theorem. If $x\in(0,1)$ then by mean value theorem we have $$\arcsin x=\arcsin x - \arcsin 0=\frac {x}{\sqrt{1-c^2}}$$ for some $c\in(0,x)$. But then we can obviously see that $$1<\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-c^2}}<\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$ Multiplying by positive $x$ we get $$x<\arcsin x<\frac{x} {\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$

Comment: I just have a small doubt. The c taken must satisfy for any value in the interval of (0,1) right?
So we are taking it for some c in the interval (0,x)

Comment: @Aghilan: yes $c\in(0,x)$ ie $0<c<x<1$.

Answer (score 3):

Let $f(x)=x-\sin^{-1} x \implies f'(x)=1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}=\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}-1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}<0$
So $f(x)$ is a decreasing function.
$$x\ge 0 \implies f(x)\le f(0) \implies f(x)\le 0$$
Next, we take $g(x)=\sin^{-1} x-\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} \implies g'(x)=\frac{-x^2}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}<0.$
So $g(x)$ is decreasing function, then
$$ x \ge 0 \implies g(x)\le g(0)=0 \implies 
\sin^{-1}x \le \frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}.$$

Comment: @Z Ahmed I understand the second part but the first part doesn't  prove $x< sin^{-1}x$

Comment: @Aghilan Oh! thanks now please see I have corrected it.

Answer (score 2):

For $|x|<1$,

$$1<\frac1{\sqrt{1-x^2}}<\frac1{(1-x^2)^{3/2}}$$ seems obvious. Then by integration between $0$ and $x$ you get the claimed inequalities.

Comment: thanks for the interesting answer

Comment: @Aghilan: any analytical proof will be equivalent to this. For geometric proofs, you need to show equivalence of the geometric axioms and analytic ones.